# Connectivity action broadcastreceiver equivalent in manifest

Tags: android

I set up my receiver like this:

```
networkReceiver = new NetworkChangesReceiver();
IntentFilter connFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(networkReceiver, connFilter);
```

I'd like to make the setup in manifest file. However, I can't find CONNECTIVITY_ACTION among android attributes for intent filter...

**edit:
I managed to find it, but on manifest I get this warning:
"Exported receiver does not require permission"
And this is not true as I have this line as well:
    
and, by debugging, I see that receiver is perfectly working and no "missing permissions" exception is ever thrown.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this one, that's what I use `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`

Comment: I don't have it...maybe because I'm using frojo apis?

Comment: Ok, it was just dumb of eclipse not showing it to me..but now I have a related problem, as you can see in the edit

Comment: Your edit's problem is just lint, make android:exported="false" and not warning anymore.